# "contains" in Bigquery standard SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I wish to migrate from Legacy SQL to Standard SQL

I had the following code in Legacy SQL

```
SELECT
  hits.page.pageTitle
FROM [mytable] 
WHERE hits.page.pageTitle contains '%'
```

And I tried this in Standard SQL:

```
SELECT
  hits.page.pageTitle
FROM `mytable` 
WHERE STRPOS(hits.page.pageTitle, "%")
```

But it gives me this error:

> Error: Cannot access field page on a value with type
>   ARRAY> at [4:21]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this one:

```
SELECT 
  hits.page.pageTitle
FROM `table`,
UNNEST(hits) hits
WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(hits.page.pageTitle, r'%')
LIMIT 1000
```

In ga_sessions schema, "hits" is an ARRAY (that is, REPEATED mode). You need to apply the [UNNEST](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#flattening-arrays) operation in order to work with arrays in BigQuery.

Comment: Hi @Will Thank you. But it doesn't give me the same result as Legacy. Why is it so?

Comment: What is different from the Legacy result? They should be both equal indeed.

Comment: It gives me only one row of data.

Comment: ops, I used `hits.page.pagepath` instead of `hits.page.pageTitle`. Could you please try it again with my updated query?

Comment: Glad it helped :)